# I'm getting two different values for an Angular Service attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm setting up a simple login in my web application. After the user is logged in, it has the option to logout the application. But when the login component is called, the first thing I verify if a user has already logged in, so I can send him to the home page. So when I try to log out, this user is not being cleaned correctly. That way the user is not sent to the log in page again. If I refresh the browser, then it works fine.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<AuthUser>;
    public currentUser: Observable<AuthUser>;

    constructor(
        private _httpClient: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AuthUser>(
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
        );
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): AuthUser {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(loginRequest): Promise<any> {
        //http call then...
        this.currentUserSubject.next(response);
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);

        //THIS LOGS NULL
        console.log(this.currentUserValue);
    }
}
```

Then when I call authService.logout() from another component:

```
logout(): void {
    this._authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
}
```

This route goes to the LoginComponent which is as follows:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _authService: AuthenticationService) {
        let loggedUser;
        this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
            loggedUser = user;
        });

        //THIS LOGS THE OLD OBJECT
        console.log(this._authService.currentUserValue);
        //THIS ALSO LOGS THE OLD OBJECT
        console.log(loggedUser);
        if (loggedUser) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
   }
}
```

How do I get the new null value inside the LoginComponent ?

Comment: The subscription is happening asynchronously, so the `subscribe` code is happening later than the code you are logging. Did you try to put your `if` logic inside your subscription so it is checked when the subscription completes?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel yes man! I also added a console.log inside the subscription and it logs the old user object :S

    this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
        console.log(user);
        loggedUser = user;
    });

Comment: You aren't providing the `AuthenticationService` in any `providers` array in a module, right?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I am. I have the AuthModule which has
const routes = [
    {
        path     : 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
];
...............
providers    : [
        AuthenticationService
    ]

Comment: That is probably your issue. See if commenting that out fixes things. Every time you are providing a service, it creates a singleton at that root. So, you have one instance at your app root module (via your `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` code) and another in your `AuthModule`. This means any components in your `AuthModule` will be using a different reference than everywhere else in your code.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel you're the man! Removing it did the trick. Also gave me a better understanding on how DI works on Angular. Thank you man!!
If you want to answer the question bellow, I'll be glad to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem stemmed from having the `AuthenticationService` provided in multiple locations. One location was in app root via the `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` code. The second was in the `AuthModule` via the `providers` array.

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services) discuss the nature of service registration and what it means when providing it in different ways:

- `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` - Creates a single, shared instance of the service across the app.
- `@NgModule({ providers: [...] })` - Creates a single, shared instance of the service across all components in the module.
- `@Component({ providers: [...] })` - Creates a new instance of the service with each instance of the component.

Comment: Thanks so much!! 12 A.M. here and you just saved me